# Where are the proxy profile options?

Tags: 11.10, proxy

Before 11.10, one could save many proxy configurations as profiles, so one could have a config for home and another for work in a laptop. Now that I've updated to 11.10, I no longer have that option.

So, how can I configure a proxy profile for my home and one for my job?

By the way, the proxy configuration has been merged into the network configuration.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). It appears to already be reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/844535)

Comment: @MarcoCeppi : Just to point that i couldn't know it's a bug. From my point of view, it could be a feature moved to another place just as the proxy configuration was moved to network configuration, or it could be a bug. The only way to know if it is a new way to config the proxy profiles or if it is a bug is asking first.

Answer (score 1):

Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/844535

[This page](http://www.gnomeshell.com/2011/04/29/old-network-proxy-settings-not-working-in-gnome3/) claims Gnome3 moved the proxy location, and offers a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I just passed this upstream to Gnome so hopefully we might get some more information in the near future.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=664901